# SQUID Proxy tcp_ougoing_address not working

Tags: proxy, squid

I have setup squid proxy on a centos 7 server (with plesk on it). whilst connected to the proxy, if I visit http://www.whatismyip.com/ it shows the ip of the server : 193.70.X.X So far so good.

I have a second IP I'd like to use so when I visit whatismyip.com it shows me this one : 79.137.X.X

So what I've tried is to add those rules : 
acl home src 83.155.X.X
tcp_outgoing_address 79.137.46.210 home

But when I do that the proxy refuses the connexion.

Can someone please help me on that ?

Comment: mayve acl home allow is missing?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's not missing. I've got this line :
http_access allow home

Answer (score 0):

Biggest mistake ever : 
I forgot to add the new IP to the server. Well in fact I thought the IP was already in use on this server as I used it a while ago. 
I've added it via plesk and it's all working just fine.
Hope this can help